# Outlook 2016 won't stop checking writing style

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

My manager has just been upgraded to Office 2016. Since then he has been annoyed by outlook constantly saying his writing is "passive" or has some other writing error when it's fine for an email.

I've tried turning off grammar and style checking within outlook's options, which stops it for a little while. However, every time outlook is restarted it just starts doing it again.

Has anyone experienced this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Click the File > Options.

Select Mail > Spelling and Autocorrect button 
[image]

In Proofing section, uncheck the "Check spelling as you type" option and "Mark grammar errors as you type".

[image]

Similar Thread I have found: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85b17e37-1dde-4176-8ab2-cd66c5a2a72a/outlook-2003-spell-check-without-user-intervention?forum=outlook